# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to read the data from excel for Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to read one excel file which has list of user name and password.
I get "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2"

My Excel looks like this

UserName---Password
U1  P1

U2  P2

U3 P3

U4  P4

Meaning, it has 2 columns and 5 rows. I dont want the first row to be taken into count, so i have given     Object data[][] = new Object[rows-1][cols];

Kindly assist in resolving the issue. THanks,

```
package com;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class LoginTest {

    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void doLogin(String userName, String password){


    }
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData(){

        Xls_Reader xls = new Xls_Reader("E:\\Pessoal\\QTPSelenium\\Excel\\Login.xlsx");
        int rows = xls.getRowCount("Login");
        System.out.println("Row Count---"+rows);
        int cols = xls.getColumnCount("Login");
        System.out.println("Column Count---"+cols);

        Object data[][] = new Object[rows-1][cols];

        for(int rNum=2;rNum<=rows;rNum++){
            for(int cNum=0;cNum<=cols;cNum++){
                System.out.println(xls.getCellData("Login", cNum, rNum));
//ERROR IN THIS LINE
                    data[rNum][cNum] = xls.getCellData("Login", cNum, rNum);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
```

I get error in this line

```
                data[rNum][cNum] = xls.getCellData("Login", cNum, rNum);
```

Comment: what are the values of rows and cols ? And, could you share the excel as well?

Comment: seems like you are doing a 0-based index for rows and 1-based index for columns `new Object[rows-1][cols];` so, you might want to use `data[rNum-1][cNum]` to assign the value.

Comment: Hi @Sachin. No I am not. I have 5 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: You are using the same index `rNum` to access the spreadsheet and array `data`. you need to use `data[rNum-1][cNum]`. If you use a debugger and see just till the exception is thrown, you'll see that `data[0][]` is always null

Comment: @Sachin. Its still not working. It is still throwing me the same exception. I used this data[rNum-1][cNum] still didn't work

Comment: debug through the code. i'm sure you'll find the solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int rNum=1;rNum<rows;rNum++){
            for(int cNum=0;cNum<cols;cNum++){
                System.out.println(xls.getCellData("Login", rNum, cNum));
                    data[rNum-1][cNum] = xls.getCellData("Login", rNum, cNum);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I also tried  data[rNum-2][cNum] = xls.getCellData("Login", cNum, rNum); Still not working

Comment: could you tell what are the values of rows and cols from the console?
Means, what is the output of 
System.out.println("Row Count---"+rows);
System.out.println("Column Count---"+cols);

Comment: and also check params of xls.getCellData("Login", cNum, rNum)
it should be xls.getCellData("Login", rNum, cNum) I believe

Comment: Sure friends. Will check and post the results

Answer (score 0):

"for(int cNum=0;cNum<=cols;cNum++)"

please change "cNum<=cols" to "cNum